# Nativescript cannot find module '@nativescript/angular/router'

Tags: angular-ui-router, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing an app using nativescript and angular 11.0. For initial startup creating a login screen. Facing issues while running the application. Get the below exception. The issue happens only when routing is enabled in the module.

```
ERROR in ./app/login/login.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@nativescript/angular/router' in 'D:\Mobile_dev\ns-ng-quiz\app-ns-ng\src\app\login'
     @ ./app/login/login.component.ts 3:0-64 5:0-51 40:113-132 78:38-57
     @ ./app/app.module.ts
     @ ./main.ts
```

ng update says everything is in order. Deleting node_modules folder and a fresh npm install did not help either.

Here is my package.json

```
{
      "name": "@nativescript/template-hello-world-ng",
      "main": "main.js",
      "version": "7.0.8",
      "author": "NativeScript Team <oss@nativescript.org>",
      "description": "NativeScript Application",
      "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
      "publishConfig": {
        "access": "public"
      },
      "keywords": [
        "nativescript",
        "mobile",
        "angular",
        "{N}",
        "template"
      ],
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "<fill-your-repository-here>"
      },
      "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~11.0.0",
        "@nativescript/angular": "~11.0.0",
        "@nativescript/core": "~7.0.0",
        "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
        "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.0",
        "@nativescript/android": "7.0.1",
        "@nativescript/types": "~7.0.0",
        "@nativescript/webpack": "~3.0.0",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "~11.0.0",
        "typescript": "~4.0.0"
      },
      "private": "true",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      }
    }
```

Here is my app-routing.module.ts

```
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "@nativescript/angular";

import { ItemsComponent } from "./item/items.component";
import { ItemDetailComponent } from "./item/item-detail.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    
    {path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full" },
    {path:"login", component:LoginComponent},
    {path:"home", component:HomeComponent}
   //{ path: "", redirectTo: "/items", pathMatch: "full" },
   // { path: "items", component: ItemsComponent },
   // { path: "item/:id", component: ItemDetailComponent }
   
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
        enableTracing:true
    })],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Project Structure in VSCode

[image: Project structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to import both `RouterExtensions` for navigation and `NativeScriptRouterModule` in the module from `@nativescript/angular` instead of the previous `@nativescript/angular/router` path.

```js
import { RouterExtensions } from '@nativescript/angular'
```

Comment: After importing the '@antivescript/angular' the issue resolved. The next thing coming in place the navigation not working as expected. There is no exception caught in the terminal. The below code used for navigating another component from my login screen. `this.routerExtensions.navigate(["../home"],{ clearHistory: true });`

Comment: By adding the below code in my app.component.html. The component navigation is working as expected.                                                                                                 
 `<page-router-outlet  actionBarVisibility="never"></page-router-outlet>`